# Where can i get a popout side control ajax?

Tags: ajax, controls

Im looking for a control similar to:

http://www.treehugger.com/files/2009/01/built-in-dishwasher-vs-hand-washing-which-greener.php

[the control on the left]  Could anyone tell me of a good free one that we can distrubute with our web based software preferably that has an Mit licence.  Cheers
Pq

Answer (score 0):

You can try out this [jQuery ‘Tab Slide Out’ Plugin](http://wpaoli.building58.com/2009/09/jquery-tab-slide-out-plugin/).

Here's a [demo link](http://www.building58.com/examples/tabSlideOut.html). It is open-source.